# Remotely Connecting to a Raring Ringtail Desktop from Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, software-recommendation, windows-8, remote-desktop, vnc

I have an Ubuntu(13.04) computer on my home network and frequently want to access it remotely from my Windows 8 PC (Like an RDP session on 2 Windows PCs). I have found a few solutions, but many are for older versions of Ubuntu and/or Windows.

I was looking in to using a VNC client on my Windows machine, but did not find any with good reviews that seemed up-to-date.

If anyone can suggest a Windows VNC client, an Ubuntu RDP server, or another method of connecting to my Ubuntu machine, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try TightVNC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For desktop sharing in Ubuntu to work you can install xrdp to allow connection from Windows 8 Remote Desktop.  To install xrdp in Ubuntu, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Note:you can run below command to disable this service when done

```
sudo service xrdp stop
```

Also you can try [VNC SERVER](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-13-04-ubuntu-12-10.html)

Another way of doing it, is using Desktop Sharing.  Just type desktop in dash, and click on it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try these solutions tonight; But I think at least one of them is bound to work!

Answer (score 0):

Install XRDP

`sudo apt-get install xrdp`

Then you can RDP into your Ubuntu machine.