# How to share current desktop through tightvnc

Tags: android, vnc

Is it possible to share my current desktop in ubuntu 14.04 with tightvnc and connect and control it using an android app (vnc viewer).
I have installed tightvncserver and am able to connect with vnc viewer for android but I am brought to very basic X11 session that is not the desktop I intended to access but it is the right computer I am trying to access.

I believe it is most likely a configuration but I do not know where to change this.
I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu come with an integrated VNC server called vino. You enable it in "settings -> sharing -> share my desktop"; see for example [Remotely Connecting to a Raring Ringtail Desktop from Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320964/remotely-connecting-to-a-raring-ringtail-desktop-from-windows-8) (not sure if it applies excatly to 14.04, but should be similar).

Be warned that at this point [only unsecure connections are possible](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250) --- so you have to use it only of **very** safe networks. To disable encryption, see [Gnome 3.10 sharing desktop --- how to configure the security type for VNC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc)

Comment: Thanks Rmano for the suggestion.
I ended up trying out x11vnc and it works as it should.  I am able to control my desktop remotely with my android device using the android VNC viewer app.
The last trick is getting x11vnc to run as a service at system startup.

Comment: Which options do you use for encryption in x11vnc? I am struggling to find one which is accepted by standard viewers...

Comment: I haven't setup encryption yet, just wanted to get it to work first.
Apparently however from the other posts I've read you first need to SSH into the machine and have the x11vnc setup to loop back to localhost.
Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this yet.

Comment: Rmano do you happen to be getting an authentication error (the authentication/security mechanism requested is not supported by this computer) when trying to connect to the x11vnc machine with the vnc viewer app for android?

Comment: Yes, with vino I happen to have that error (the same I have in Windows clients). Seems that with x11vnc it works, but I have to check more.

Comment: I believe we just need to setup our Xserver (whatever its called in ubuntu) to tunnel SSH connections to the Xserver session running on the local host.